# halt execution until an observer subscribed to emits value

Tags: angular

I have this simple component, with several methods inside it. All the methods will make use of the variable todaysQuote. I didn't want to call the service that sets its value from each method; instead I want to set it on component initialization once and use it in the rest of the methods.

Now the problem is at times, todaysQuote remains undefined while at times it does have the correct value. What is the best way to handle such a scenario? I am thinking that halting further execution until it contains a value is the way to go but am a bit lost on how to do that exactly.

While I can convert the service method to promise with toPromise(), I don't have the right to change its observable implementation.

```
 export class MemComponent implements OnInit {
    private todaysQuote : number;

    ngOnInit() {

      this.ValueService
      .todayQuote()
      .subscribe(value=>{
        this.todaysQuote = value;
      })
  }


  methodOne(){
     // do something based on todaysQuote
      }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) out undesirable values, such as `undefined`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceSubscription = this.ValueService
      .todayQuote()
      .pipe(filter(val => {
        //filter out anything else!
        return value != undefined;
      }))
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.todaysQuote = value;
      });
}
```

For anything below RxJS 6, you don't use a `pipe`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceSubscription = this.ValueService
      .todayQuote()
      .filter(val => {
        //filter out anything else!
        return value != undefined;
      })
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.todaysQuote = value;
      }); 
}
```

Comment: i did import { filter } from 'rxjs/operator/filter'; and tried to test it out but it doesn't compile. filter generates error No overload method for this call. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/564#issuecomment-344372463 makes sense but still I cant run it.

Comment: What version of Angular/RxJS are you using?

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.5.12", "@angular/core": "^5.0.0-rc.1",

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below,

> I am thinking that halting further execution until it contains a value.

I think it's okay to follow this approach.

so add a method to execute the other logic, which depends on the **`todaysQuote`**.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.ValueService.todayQuote().subscribe(value => {
        if(value) {
          this.todaysQuote = value;
          this.commonMethodName();     <-- add a method to execute the other logics 
        }
      })
  }

  commonMethodName() {
      this.methodOne();
      this.methodTwo();
  }

  methodOne(){
     // do something based on todaysQuote
      }
```

hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks @ganesh045 while it works, it forces the methods to be called sort of automatically.